# Does Pandoc have text substitution macros?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Say I want to have a bunch of metadata at the top of a file such as 
`AUTHOR: Foo Bar` `DATE: Jan 21 2052`. Now whenever I use the word AUTHOR somewhere in the file, I would like it to be substituted by `Foo Bar` and DATE by `Jan 21 2052`

Does the markdown extension of Pandoc provide this feature?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53355628/2425163

Comment: From how you describe your wish, I cannot see why this should be implemented as a *Pandoc* feature. This is simply a question of 'search and replace' which can be accomplished by ***`sed`***: `cat source.markdown | sed 's#AUTHOR #Foo Bar #g;s#DATE #Jan 21 2052 #g;s' | pandoc --to=html --from=markdown -o source.html`

Comment: Yes I was also able to achieve this using the m4 (https://ss64.com/bash/m4.html) command-line tool which expands embedded macros automatically.

Answer (score 0):

No, Pandoc does *not* have a substitution feature (as of version 3.1.12).

However, as mentioned in the comments you can do this with the following Lua filter ([from the Pandoc documenation](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#replacing-placeholders-with-their-metadata-value)):

```lua
local vars = {}

function get_vars (meta)
  for k, v in pairs(meta) do
    if pandoc.utils.type(v) == 'Inlines' then
      vars["%" .. k .. "%"] = {table.unpack(v)}
    end
  end
end

function replace (el)
  if vars[el.text] then
    return pandoc.Span(vars[el.text])
  else
    return el
  end
end

return {{Meta = get_vars}, {Str = replace}}
```

See also [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53372026/65889).